# Sylius Authentication failing on homepage alone

Tags: symfony, sylius

a bit of a weird

On every page except my homepage I have "Authentication: no" showing in the Symfony, but when I check other pages I am logged in as expected.

I have tried clearing cache, session, and logging in and out and it remains. I discovered this from printing app.user as I'm using it in if statements.

I have also watched logs as logging in but everything is working fine!

I'm not sure how else to debug this - I also have this issue on my production server so I'm sure its application based

if anyone can suggest anything I would appreciate the thoughts/help

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try to change you security.yml file from:

```
sylius.security.shop_regex: "^/(?!admin|api/.*|api$|media/.*)[^/]++"
```

To

```
sylius.security.shop_regex: "^/(?!admin|api/.*|api$|media/.*)"
```

I'm using Sylius 1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove the localised urls? Please check the sylius.security.shop_regex settings:

http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/cookbook/disabling-localised-urls.html

Comment: Please add a short explanation in your answer of what the post that you linked to explains.